# Using skin to close low-voltage circuit

Tags: led, led-driver, low-voltage, touch

I am trying to create a ping pong ball sized light-up ball that should light up when held in my hand, as in the 80's toy inspired by the movie/television series "Star man".

The circuit must be powered by a coin battery cell, preferable a 1.5 V LR44.

I have a [ZXSC380FHTA](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXSC380.pdf) LED driver and a 47 μH or 100 μH RF inductor.

The LED is a standard 5 mm white LED from a broken computer fan which lights up using only the LR44 button cell, LED driver, and inductor.

I have tried with a 2N2222A transistor to drive the touch (skin) switch and even tried to create a Darlington transistor by combining two of these, but no success.

So far I only tried on a breadboard to get a skin connection using two pins. Is the surface area to the skin insufficient, or is there something wrong with the electrical design?

Does anyone have a suggestion?

When driven by 5 V from an Arduino it is no problem to light up the LED with just a transistor and using the skin to close the circuit between +5 V and transistor base, but when transitioning to 1.5 V I guess there is too little voltage to drive even an LED driver of the type mentioned above.

Also, should the load, i.e. the LED driver/inductor/LED be placed at the collector or emitter side of the transistor?

Update:
When using 3 x 2n2222a in a darlington config, I can get the led to shine using a 3V coin cell. But only if the finger is licked a little before pushing the two pins I use to test this on the breadboard. I will try to use a bigger piece of metal as connector next and maybe order some triple darlington transistors to further test.
Also when googling: "energy ball" seem to hit a simulcrum of what I want, the nowadays sold "energy balls" doesn't light up, but blink and make annoying noises. Which to some might seem like an improvement but to me seem like; "Oh why, for the love of a hot women (or man, if you are so inclined)."

Comment: Some of them that I've used have two small metal contacts on the outside of the ball similar to a ping-pong ball. When both were in skin contact the ball would light up. I believe they used three BJTs, not two. I've since designed a circuit that can be used for similar purposes -- was designed to detect even slightly moist surfaces -- and I may be able to find the design (or recreate it) at some time later.

Comment: As in three BJT's in a darlington configuration?

Comment: Well, in my case not exactly. But in your current situation, assuming you are willing to have two contacts protrude the ball, I'd try that as a "next step." It might get you there.

Comment: you want a 3v cell (or two in series( and at least a darlington, maybe 2. basically, build a ghost detector and backoff the transistor count until you have to actually touch it to light.

Answer (score 0):

I have made [one of these](https://www.circuits-diy.com/static-electricity-detector-using-2n3819-mosfet/) in the past and they are certainly sensitive. You might need some kind of ESD protection but there are lots of interesting possibilities with this

[image]

Comment: The 2n3819 might be better than a 2n2222a transistor for my project. But will it work as I described in my question, i e closing two metal points with the skin turn on the Drain-Source current flow? And if so should those metal points be between the gate and battery +? Will it work with a 1.5v battery and a led driver?

Comment: The pictured circuit constantly drains the battery